# How to compare strings that shows number of differences

Tags: c++, string

I'm new to programming so I'm sorry if my question is hard to understand.

I have a string modelAnswer as such

```
string modelAnswer = "ABABACDA";
```

So it's supposed to be the answers to a quiz and I'm trying to make it so that if user's input is
`string studentAnswer = "ABADBDBB";` for example the program will show that I have gotten 3 points as the first three letters of the studentAnswer string matches the modelAnswer.

Comment: iterate through the string and compare each element.

Comment: You could compare the two strings char by char.

Comment: You can use [std::mismatch](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/mismatch) in a loop, until it returns the end iterators, to find the set of differences.

Comment: What did you come up with when you thought about the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can use standard algorithm `std::inner_product` as for example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <numeric>
#include <functional>

int main() 
{
    std::string   modelAnswer( "ABABACDA" );
    std::string studentAnswer( "ABADBDBB" ); 

    auto n = std::inner_product( modelAnswer.begin(), modelAnswer.end(),
                                 studentAnswer.begin(), size_t( 0 ),
                                 std::plus<size_t>(), std::equal_to<char>() );

    std::cout << n << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
3
```

It is assumed that the strings have the same length. Otherwise you should use the less string as the first pair of arguments.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>

int main() 
{
    std::string   modelAnswer( "ABABACDA" );
    std::string studentAnswer( "ABADBDBB" ); 

    auto n = std::inner_product( modelAnswer.begin(), 
                                 std::next( modelAnswer.begin(), std::min( modelAnswer.size(), studentAnswer.size() ) ),
                                 studentAnswer.begin(), size_t( 0 ),
                                 std::plus<size_t>(), std::equal_to<char>() );

    std::cout << n << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow, great insight (aside from the use of `std::endl` <g>). I was thinking about `count_if` and a lambda, but this is much better.

Comment: @PeteBecker Common-used alternatives for the family of count algorithms are std::accumulate and std::inner_product.:)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using standard strings, with the proper includes (Mainly `#include <string>`), you can write a simple for loop to iterate over each character, comparing them.

```
std::string answer = "ABABACDA";
std::string stringToCompare = "ABADBDBB";
int score = 0;
for (unsigned int i = 0; (i < answer.size()) && (i < stringToCompare.size()); ++i)
{
  if (answer[i] == stringToCompare[i])
  {
    ++score;
  }
}
printf("Compare string gets a score of %d.\n", score);
```

The above code works for me, printing the following result:

```
Compare string gets a score of 3.
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a `stringstream`, you can push one character at a time into temporary variables and test for equivalence in a loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    std::istringstream model("ABABACDA");
    std::istringstream student("ABADBDBB");
    int diff = 0;
    char m, s;

    while ((model >> m) && (student >> s))
        if (m != s) diff++;

    std::cout << diff << std::endl; // 5

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What happens if the student doesn't give enough answers?  You don't count those blanks.

Comment: It's not clear to me why using `stringstream` is an advantage here.